# How do I take input and print the whole string in java?

Tags: java

```
package fresher;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fresher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i=scan.nextInt();
        double d= scan.nextDouble();
        String name= scan.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

the above code is only accepting int and double input and without accepting string input it prints int and double

Answer (score 0):

// reading the complete line for the integer
// and converting it to an integer

```
int i=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
double d= Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
String name= scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to input string using scanner is this:

```
String s=scan.next();
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: yes but then it won't take the spaces. I hope you got my question. Its a simple program which accepts int, double and string and prints the same in reverse order. But the problem is without reading the string from console it prints the int and double.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print(s);
```